# Pandas tweet json weird characters u'�'

Tags: python, json, twitter

Not sure why but when I load tweets in a json file to pandas i get a lot of weird characters.

```
 for file_name in files:
        if '.json' in file_name:
            file_path = WORKING_DIR + '/data/' + file_name

            # Reading the json as a dict
            with open(file_path) as json_d:
                data = json.load(json_d, encoding='utf8')
                json_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
                dfs.append(json_df)
```

Comment: u'�' means it failed to decode the character with `'utf-8'` encoding. If you apply strict decoding, you will get error instead of u'�'. Is the file in some other encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `encoding='utf-16'` or `encoding='utf-8'`

for file_name in files:
        if '.json' in file_name:
            file_path = WORKING_DIR + '/data/' + file_name

```
        # Reading the json as a dict
        with open(file_path) as json_d:
            data = json.load(json_d, encoding='utf-16')
            json_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
            dfs.append(json_df)
```

As @MYGz Suggested "u'�' means it failed to decode the character with 'utf-8'"
So try using other encoding.